# Express JS empty string instead of null in ejs templates

Tags: node.js, express

I have so many `.ejs` templates in an expressjs project and when some variable value is null. It just print "null" in place of variable. But I want nothing to be printed where a variable is null. 
For example: 
I have two variables `first_name` and `last_name` with values "John" and null. In this case I want only value of first_name to be printed But I am getting John null.

I know I can first check if a variable is not null then only I should display it. But as I said I have a project with so many ejs files. Therefore I want this behaviour as default. I mean some sort of configuration with which I can tell express to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
<% var firstName = 'John', lastName = null; %>
<%= firstName %><%= lastName %>
```

In this case the output will be `John` only i.e. not with the null printed.
Make sure the lastName is not a string i.e. `'null'`. In that case, the lastName **will** be printed.